# vsvars32.bat Windows 8 can't set PATH-variable

Tags: batch-file, path

we have a batch-file, which helps us updating the TFS with some new DLL-files.
Before we do anything, we set the vs2010 variables per vsvars32.bat:

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
```

This doesn't seem to work on our new Windows 8 machines, I keep getting the error "Management was unexpected at this time".
I've found this Thread: https://superuser.com/questions/119610/spaces-and-parenthesis-in-windows-path-variable-screws-up-batch-files

Where they suggest to escape all paths, but the vsvars32.bat is already doing this:

```
@set "PATH=%VSINSTALLDIR%Team Tools\Performance Tools;%PATH%"
```

I'm quite a newbie in such stuff, since I'm normally programming. Am I doing anything wrong here? I'm quite sure the problem lies in such a path:

```
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
```

As usual, thanks a lot for all replies and a good start in the week.

Matthias

Comment: most people have a `PATH` with parentheses:  `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Comment: But the vsvars32.bat already sets  the Path in parantheses, should I edit my path-variable manually so that every path is in parantheses? So something like "Path1";"Path2" etc.?

Comment: just a idea: is your `set "path=..."` inside a code block (between a `(` and a `)`? Perhaps inside an `if` or `for` construct?

Comment: vsvars32.bat is a Batch file, which is shipped with VS2010 I'd say, I'm not sure its a good idea to tinker arround it.
It's interesting nobody else has that problem, since everybody, who uses this bat-file with W8 might run into that problem.

Comment: Hm seems like a Program, which I dont know has messed up with the PATH-Variable, I correct it and everything fine.